# Ckeditor - user friendly image upload

Tags: django, ckeditor

I have ckeditor 4 with image upload on my website. Everything works great the only issue is that it visually looks very bad. Is it possible to style or change the UI for the image upload as I expect users will have a hard time understanding it. I just want a simple upload button nothing fancy

Update:
I discovered the [easy image plugin](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/easyimage.html) and it does exactly what i need, just a simple image upload button. The issue is it requires a cloud service subscription so it wont work for me.

[image]

[image: enter image descr iption here]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this to remove all the dialog tabs and just kept the image upload tab

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': { 
        'removeDialogTabs': 'image:advanced;image:Link;image:info',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add style and customize the input, one way could be:

```
{%if field.name  == 'picture' %}
  <label for ="id_picture" id="icon_upload" class="fa fa-camera"></label>
  <input type="file" name="picture" id="id_picture" accept="image/*"style="display: none;" >
{% endif %}
```

the field name usually is take of the field name model,, but it can change depending on how the form is passed to a template.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However I don't think this will work as the 'image button' is not a form field

Comment: This is an example like you can customize your form. You could be more specific about what you need? and also tell us how you are creating the form and the view because from the form and / or the view you can also add attributes to customize it.

Comment: The form has a "content" field that is a RichTextUploadingField so I can use ckeditor on it. The ckeditor tool bar has a image upload feature that i have working. The issue is that the view you see above is not very user friendly and I want just a simple upload button when the user clicks it opposed to all of the extra features seen in the screen shot